# how to calculate the value from one input without eval() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i calculate the value of a single input without using `eval()` ? in the code below it just does that but I used the eval function which is said to be harmful and a bad decision, is it possible to output the result in console, ex: if you put in there 1+1 i want the result in console and without the `eval()` function?

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
class Math extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      input: '',
      value: "",
    }
  }

 
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
      console.log(e.target.value)
    
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = eval(this.state.input)
    this.setState({value})
    console.log(value)
  
  }



  render(){
    return(
      <div>
         <div className="func">
            <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="68+1" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
         <button>=</button>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
}


export default Math;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want a mathematical expression parser? These exist (and aren't difficult to make simple versions of).

Comment: yea man, that code from the question works when you type in the input 1+1 you get the result in console but i want to make that without eval() function if is possible somehow.

Comment: Ideally, using the onBlur() or onChange() event, you can capture the user input and process accordingly. However, not sure what you are looking for?

Comment: @TudorAlexandru Right. You need a mathematical expression parser/runner, whether an existing one, or one you create. Sorry, I thought I said that.

Comment: @DaveNewton yea, I think that it is, I will go to find more about that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library to evaluate the math expression on the input [math-expression-evaluator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/math-expression-evaluator). Make sure to catch errors in case the expression is not valid.

Comment: Yea, i think that it is, I will go to research more about that, thanks, and thanks to @Dave Newton too.

Answer (score 0):

setState is an asynchronous function, you can't  immeditealy get the stated value. So handleSubmit method should look like this if you want to print value.

```js
 

 
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = eval(this.state.input)
    // You can also log the value here, you do not need to read from state
    console.log(value)
    this.setState({value : value}).then(()=> {
      console.log(this.state.value)
    })      
 }
```

But avoiding eval is highly recommended. You can check regular expressions to parse the input and calculate the result.

Comment: I don't think regex are the best solution for a mathematical expression parser.